# Is there a word that means badge/ hallmark but has a negative connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, connotation

I want something for the sentence:

> Being a minority is not a _____ of shame but a badge of honor.

Edit:
I wanted the parallel between ____ and badge. See the accepted answer for details. 
Thanks to all who contributed!

Comment: Erm... [**badge** of shame](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22badge+of+shame%22) ***does*** have "negative connotations".

Comment: "certificate of shame" may fit.

Comment: The phrase "scarlet letter" is occasionally used in this figurative sense.  See also http://english.stackexchange.com/q/10623/13804

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider **[mantle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mantle)**.

Being a minority does not confer a mantle of shame, but rather a badge of honor.

From Merriam-Webster linked above:

> Definition of mantle
>
> 1]
>      a :  a loose sleeveless garment worn over other clothes :  cloak
>
> b :  a figurative cloak symbolizing preeminence or authority of leadership>>
>
> 2]
>       a :  something that covers, enfolds, or envelops (see envelop 1)

Since minorities sometimes endeavor to hide their status (for example by changing their name to something that sounds less Hispanic, German or Jewish) 'mantle' may fit as both a figurative cloak and as a concealment. Examples would include Martin Sheen (Ramón Antonio Gerardo Estévez), Jack Benny (Benny Kubelsky), etc.

Answer (score 24):

"A **mark** of shame" fits your sentence, but "A **brand** of shame" might be even better here.

**Brand** 3b (1) : a mark put on criminals with a hot iron (2) : a mark of disgrace : stigma  ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brand))

Comment: I think this is a better fit than "stigma" for the particular sentence in the question.

Comment: I disagree with your suggestion that "brand" may be better than "mark", but +1 for "mark".  :-)

Answer (score 19):

The word *stigma* implies both the 'badge' and the 'shame':

> a mark of shame or discredit

<sub>source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stigma)</sub>

But as @FumbleFingers [notes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/371984/is-there-a-word-that-means-badge-hallmark-but-has-a-negative-connotation#comment870699_371984), *badge* is an OK choice here as well.

Comment: +1: not an easy question but "_stigma_" looks like a perfect fit to me.

Comment: Yep! Stigma is a perfect fit and unfortunately widely used in this context +1.

Comment: Only my opinion, but colloquially "stigma" seems more often to be about reactions or perceptions than any objective reality.  If you said that "Being a minority is not a stigma but a badge of honor," you'd be saying in effect that "Most people will honor you rather than look down on you for being a minority."  Which, I believe, is not quite the idea the OP is getting at.  The drift of the original sentence seems to be more like, "Regardless of how others might try to shame you for being a minority, you should realize it's actually a badge of honor."

Answer (score 4):

As suggested already, the suffix "*of shame*" qualifies *badge* itself as a fitting word.
The word ***symbol*** can replace *badge*.

> Being a minority is not a ***symbol*** of shame but a badge of honor.

ODO:

> **[symbol](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/symbol)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **2** A thing that represents or stands for something else, especially a material object representing something abstract.
>
> ‘In another essay, he presents the character as a symbol of the mental
>   retardation of our society.’

If you are looking for a word ***implicitly*** meaning *badge of shame*, you may actually use the word ***shame*** itself.

> Being a minority is not a ***shame*** but a badge of honor.

Also, ***disgrace*** may work in place of *shame*.

M-W:

> **[shame](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shame)**
>   *noun*
>
> **2 :**  a condition of humiliating disgrace or disrepute :  ignominy : *the **shame** of being arrested*
>
> **[disgrace](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disgrace)**
>   *noun*
>
> :  a source of shame : *Your manners are a **disgrace**; He's a
>   **disgrace** to the profession.*

Comment: Also consider *symbolic* of shame. This sacrifices a bit of parallelism, but is perhaps more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind excising "of shame" in your sample sentence, the first thing that came to my mind was **stain**:

> Your minority status is not an indelible stain on your character, but a badge of honor.

[Dictionary entry](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stain?s=t):

> 3. a cause of reproach; stigma; blemish: *a stain on one's reputation.*

Comment: Exactly, "not a stigma, but a badge of honor" was what first came to my mind as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "stamp". To me, it can have both a positive or a negative connotation, depending on which type of stamp is described. A stamp of approval is positive, a stamp of shame is negative.